# Urn problem: with and without replacement the probability of seeing last ball of particular color

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

suppose you have red and blue balls in a jar and you pick one at a time,

- if its red you replace it, additionally you do another draw and throw whichever ball comes up.
- if its blue you throw it away

Assuming R red and B blue balls, whats probability that last ball would be blue

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself?

Comment: thanks Henry, I tried expanding out the probability tree, and it seems the branches increase exponentially if you try to determine probability using this approach, you do get some insights like # paths etc. but wasnt sure about the formula. I do know its possible to do this empirically though :)

Comment: When you "replace and throw out another ball" do you replace it *before* you draw the discard, *or* draw the discard before you replace it?

Comment: replace before you discard

Comment: ok have an answer from one of my friends, if you map out the transition probabilities in a matrix, you can take the nth power (where n is the #steps to the final state) to get to the final state - not exactly a formula but close enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: After each iteration you have one less ball, and if you have $n$ total balls at a given time, $B$ blue balls and $n-B$ red balls, then you can write down a recurrence for the probability of the last ball being blue assuming you have $B$ blue out of $n$ total balls, let's denote the probability $p(n,B)$, in terms of $p(n-1,B)$ and $p(n-1,B-1)$ after you apply your random drawing process one time. You can try to find a pattern and prove it with this recursion, or just attack the recursion directly if you know how.

Comment: thanks user2566092 i was trying to expand out the paths based on each less ball, I can see a pattern but the the probability changes based on the path taken (if you draw all blue or red than you have one path but if you draw a combination, you get multiple paths - something like ij+1 where i is # of red draws and j blue) - would be great if you can expand it out for me - thanks :)